# What wordpress image hooks am I looking for?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know my question will end up a bit vague, but I need direction so that I can start understanding things better. It's been a long while since I last worked with wordpress.

I want to add new image output sizes for my uploaded image. I found the add_image_size() function and the set_post_thumbnail_size() function.

What function will change the srcset image sizes for me? What function changes the default upload sizes and how do I add options to my upload sizes?[image: my produced image srcset]
[image: my available options]

Answer (score 1):

add_image_size() fits the best for your needs.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

**Update:**
Add the following to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
       'custom-size' => __('Your Custom Size Name'),
    ) );
 }
```

There is no direct hook available to get the sizes available. But you can get this using  this variable.

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After adding this tag to my functions.php, not much has changed, rather: after looking at it the uploaded image with chrome devtools, it gained another srcset image. Did I phrace my question wrong if I meant to alter my basic image upload sizes?

Comment: Can you please explain your exact problem or issue your face?

Comment: So do you mean you need to know the code that needs to place on frontend to displayed that size image on your site?

Comment: I added just the folllowing line to my `functions.php`: `add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 );` After clearing it again now adding this line, no options have been added and also no srcset has been added so I suppose I was wrong about my previous remark.

Comment: It may be worth saying I am running wordpress on uniform server from localhost. I believe it may be wrong to blame the server for this issue tho.

Comment: I did not get any idea about your issue, Can you please be detail? or explain with the help of a screenshot?

Comment: I added pics. If there is anything else you could use to help me out, just let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99142/discussion-between-pradeep-sambandam-and-puddingboy).